# Is there a physical reason for level repulsion and avoided crossings?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Suppose we have a Hamiltonian that depends on various real parameters.  When tuning the values of these parameters, the energy eigenvalues will often avoid crossing each other.  Why?

Is there a physically intuitive justification for [level repulsion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_repulsion) and [avoided crossings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoided_crossing)?  It would be nice to see a general argument.

Comment: The question (v1) is essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32041/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Actually, the question you linked is what inspired my question.  Perhaps I should have added more detail in my question, but I was thinking Adiabatic Theorem, not perturbation theory. I will edit my question correspondingly.

Comment: Concerning the Adiabatic Theorem, see also e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem).

Answer (score 9):

Consider what happens if there is a crossing.  A crossing would imply a degeneracy in the system.  A degeneracy would imply a symmetry.  It would be unnatural for a perturbation to *introduce* a symmetry into a system, and so the eigenvalues cannot cross generically, but can under special circumstances.

Comment: Only upto accidental degeneracies. For e.g. it happens in H-atom due to circular symmetric Coulomb potential V(r)

Comment: Can you show it implies a symmetry? How does the symmetry act?