# Physical intuition behind level repulsion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

In non-degenerate time-independent perturbation theory we see that the second order correction to the eigenstate energy exhibits 'level repulsion'.

Is this a purely mathematical curiousity or is there physical intuition that can be gained here?

[image: b]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is the second order perturbative correction to the ground state energy always down?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32041/2451)

Comment: It's better to type up equations in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) than to copy images. I think the answer from @Qmechanic the the linked post does answer your question though.