# Perturbation Theory: Second-order energy correction to the ground state always negative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I have read something but I cannot understand how the author came to this conclusion.

Say we have a system with a non-degenerate ground state subject to a perturbation, is it true that the second-order energy shift to the ground state energy obtained by the perturbation theory is always negative?

I will attach an image of the working, but I don't understand how his logic makes sense. Could someone perhaps explain how this chain of logic works?

[image]

Comment: We encourage people to use [MathJax (tutorial)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than images so as not to exclude our sight-impaired readers from the social/scientific equation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32041/2451

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 2nd order correction to the ground state ($n=0$) energy is always negative. The logic is that this correction is given as a sum of terms such that each term has a positive numerator (square of an absolute value $|\langle m| \hat{H}_p| n\rangle|^2$) and negative denominator ($E^{(0)}_{n=0}$ is the lowest energy eigenvalue by definition, hence $E^{(0)}_{n=0}-E^{(0)}_m$ is always negative). Thus every term is negative as is their sum.