# Why there’s level repulsion in quantum chaotic systems?

Tags: many-body, chaos-theory

What’s the physical intuition of level repulsion in thermalized quantum systems? And from the opposite, why integratable systems display a Poisson distribution of the spectrum?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32041/2451

Comment: I think it's not that related? Never did I associate this level repulsion in chaotic system with that level repulsion in perterbation theory. Or it's just not that explicit for me to see the logic. Hope someone could answer this question :)