# Intuitive reason as to why the second-order change to the energy is always negative in quantum perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

This implies that our first-order correction always overestimates the true change in the energy. I was trying to think of the second-order correction in terms of a second derivative but can't think of a good reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32041/2451